# Can't able to display fetched API data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, frontend

I am a beginner. I am developing a website on React and Using an API for fetching the data but I am not able to display it on the table view. Although I am able to log the data into the console.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import "./Hero.css"
import Search from '../../Pages/Search/Search';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Hero = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState('');
    const [unit, setUnit] = useState('');
    const [amazon, setAmazon] = useState(false);
    const [costco, setCostco] = useState(false);
    const [walmart, setWalmart] = useState(false);
    const [dollartree, setDollartree] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const history = useNavigate();

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setItem(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleUnitChange = (event) => {
        setUnit(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleAmazonChange = (event) => {
        setAmazon(event.target.checked);
    };

    const handleCostcoChange = (event) => {
        setCostco(event.target.checked);
    };

    const handleWalmartChange = (event) => {
        setWalmart(event.target.checked);
    };

    const handleDollartreeChange = (event) => {
        setDollartree(event.target.checked);
    };

    const constructAPIUrl = () => {
    const baseUrl = 'http://74.208.39.34/search';
    const queryParams = [`item=${item}`, `unit=${unit}`];

    // Add vendor query params based on checkbox values
    if (amazon) {
        queryParams.push('amazon=y');
    }

    if (costco) {
        queryParams.push('costco=y');
    }

    if (walmart) {
        queryParams.push('walmart=y');
    }

    if (dollartree) {
        queryParams.push('dollartree=y');
    }

    // Add other vendors as needed (e.g., walmart, dollartree)

    return `${baseUrl}?${queryParams.join('&')}`;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const apiUrl = constructAPIUrl();

    // Use Axios to make the API request and fetch data in JSON format
        axios
          .get(apiUrl)
          .then((response) => {
            // Handle the fetched data (e.g., update state to display it in the table)
            setData(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            history('/search');
            return response;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          });
      };


    return(
<div id="page">
    <div className="container">
        <section className="main-section">
            <div className="flex-row">
                <div className="col-2">
                    <div className="banner-ad">
                        <p>Banner Ad</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-8">
                    <div className="main-form">
                        <h1>BEST PRICE<br/>LARGEST QUANTITY!</h1>
                        <p>Find the cheapest items for sale online by the pound, ounce, gallon, quart, and more!. From Over Multiple venders </p>
                        <div className="my-form">
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="inputs">
                                    <input placeholder="Product name" className="prod-input" name="name" id="name" required="" type="text" value={item} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                                    <select value={unit} onChange={handleUnitChange} className="unit-select" name="desired_units" id="units" required="">
                                        <option selected="" value="">Select Unit</option>
                                        <option value="count">Count</option>
                                        <optgroup label="Weights &amp; Volumes">
                                            <option value="lb">Pounds</option>
                                            <option value="oz">Ounces</option>
                                            <option value="kg">Kilograms</option>
                                            <option value="g">Grams</option>
                                            <option value="mg">Milligrams</option>
                                            <option value="gal">Gallons</option>
                                            <option value="Liter">Liters</option>
                                            <option value="l">Milliliters</option>
                                            <option value="cups">Cups</option>
                                            <option value="qt">Quarts</option>
                                            <option value="pint">Pints</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                        <optgroup label="Computer Measurements">
                                            <option value="Terabyte">Terabytes (TB)</option>
                                            <option value="Gigabyte">Gigabytes (GB)</option>
                                            <option value="Megabyte">Megabytes (MB)</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="vendor-ticks">
                                <div className="vendor-head"><h2>VENDORS:</h2></div>
                                    <div className="vendor-tick-box">
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="amazon" checked={amazon} onChange={handleAmazonChange}/><label >AMAZON</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="walmart" checked={walmart} onChange={handleWalmartChange}/><label >WALMART</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="costco" checked={costco} onChange={handleCostcoChange}/><label >COSTCO</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="dollartree" checked={dollartree} onChange={handleDollartreeChange}/><label >DOLLARTREE</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="submit-btn">
                                    {/* <NavLink to="/search" className="submit-button" type="submit">Check</NavLink> */}
                                    <button type="submit">Check</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-2">
                    <div className="banner-ad">
                        <p>Banner Ad</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="brands-logo-section">
            <div className="brands-logos">
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.amazon.com" target="_blank"><img src="./amazon.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.walmart.com" target="_blank"><img src="./walmart.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.costco.com" target="_blank"><img src="./costco.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.dollartree.com " target="_blank"><img src="./dollartree.png" /></NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <Search data={data} />
</div>
    )
}

export default Hero;
```

I am fetching the data in one JSX component and displaying it in another. I am passing the data to another jsx component like this:

`<Search data={data} />`

Here is table view component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/Footer'
import './Search.css'

const Search = ({ data }) =>{
        return (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <div id="page">
                <div className="container">
                    <section className="search-result-sec">
                        <div className="flex-row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                             <div className="banner-ad">
                                <p>Banner Ad</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-8">
                            <div className="search-results">
                                {data && data.length > 0 ? (
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Href</th>
                                            <th>Product Name</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>PPU</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {data.map((itemData, index) => (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <td>{itemData.href}</td>
                                        <td>{itemData.name}</td>
                                        <td>{itemData.ppu}</td>
                                        <td>{itemData.price}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ))}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                ) : (
                                    <h2>No data available</h2>
                                  )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                         <div className="banner-ad">
                            <p>Banner Ad</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          )
    }

export default Search
```

Every time when I try to fetch the data, the code logs the data into console and load the next page but shows `No data Available` because its not getting any data in this page. Someone Please help me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: may be try removing that `history('/search');` part from your code

Answer (score 0):

First, add a `console for data` in the `Search` component and see if you are getting the data there. Also, make sure you are setting the right data coming from the response in the `data` state. Check if you are getting an array in the response from this code.

```js
axios
          .get(apiUrl)
          .then((response) => {
            // Handle the fetched data (e.g., update state to display it in the table)
            setData(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            history('/search');
            return response;
          })
```

Maybe the `response.data` is returning an object that contains the array and not the array directly.

If this doesn't please provider more context or possiblily console.log the response and share that result.

Comment: When I logged the data in the search component. It is saying `undefined`

Comment: If you could please elaborate on why are you routing to '/search' after setting the setData state? because if you are using the Search component in the same file in which you are fetching the data then why change the route?

Comment: Just because I want to show the table page after clicking the check button and there will be the table which will show the fetched data

Comment: I checked the datatype of the data, it is `object` not `array`.

Comment: what should I do now? @WaqasKhan

Comment: First of all you don't need to push to another route as the I belive the table component is the Search component ( correct me if I am wrong ) which is  already in the component that's fetching the data. Remove the `history('/search')` and also, check if the object contains an array inside of it.  Maybe it has response.data.data where the second data is the array, If you still can't find the solution we can hop on a call.

Comment: The table component is not in the hero component where I am fetching the data. Also, it doesn't contain the array inside the object, it only object. I tried doing `response.data.data` but doesn't worked out.

Comment: If you can come on a call it would be really great as I can explain my problem better. @WaqasKhan

Comment: @HenryVjem Apologies for the very very late reply, I was kind of stuck in some issues. I hope you have solved the issues if not, I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the timing of fetching the data and rendering the Search component. When you fetch the data using the API and update the data state in the Hero component, it causes a re-render. However, at this point, the Search component might already be rendered without receiving the updated data prop.
you are using `history('/search')` after setting the data in the state. Instead, you should use `history.push('/search')` to navigate to the search page after the data is fetched and the state is updated

Comment: I have used useNavigate instead of useHistory because useHistrory is replaced by useNavigate that's why its history('/search') and not history.push('/search')